# Current User Location data in Next.js fetching extremely slowly

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-google-maps

I have a `fetchDisplayMaps` component that displays a list of restaurants based on the user's current location. This is achieved by calculating the distance between the user's current location in  `LocationContext.tsx` and the location of the restaurants, and then displaying the restaurants within a predetermined radius in `fetchDisplayMaps.tsx`.

The problem with my current implementation is, whil it takes FOREVER to fetch the user's current location, the appropriate restaurants can only be displayed once the current location of the user has been determined. This is obviously not good for user experience. I'm using `react-google-maps` API to fetch the user's current location. From my experience and observation, it shouldn't take nearly as long as it's currently taking (⁓20s) to achieve this.

I've tried different methods of fetching the user's current location. I've also tried to wrap individual components with context providers selectively to expedite the process of fetching the current location of the user while achieving efficiency by avoiding re-renders, all to no avail. It seems the delay is primarily due to the time it takes to fetch the user's current location.

Code:

fetch user's current location:

**app/context/LocationContext.tsx:**

```
"use client";

import {
  RestaurantMenuProvider,
  useRestaurantMenuContext,
} from "./RestaurantMenuContext";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import {
  LocationContextValue,
  LocationProviderProps,
  Restaurant,
} from "types/types";

const libraries: (
  | "places"
  | "drawing"
  | "geometry"
  | "localContext"
  | "visualization"
)[] = JSON.parse(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_LIBRARIES ?? '["places", "geometry"]'
);

const LocationContext = createContext<LocationContextValue | undefined>(
  undefined
);

export const useLocationContext = (): LocationContextValue => {
  const context = useContext(LocationContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useLocationContext must be used within a LocationProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

function calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(
  location1: google.maps.LatLng,
  location2: google.maps.LatLng
) {
  const distanceInMeters =
    window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
      location1,
      location2
    );
  return distanceInMeters / 1000;
}

export const LocationProvider: React.FC<LocationProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const { restaurantData, setRestaurantData } = useRestaurantMenuContext();
  const [currentLocation, setCurrentLocation] =
    useState<null | google.maps.LatLng>(null);
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [restaurantLocation, setRestaurantLocation] =
    useState<google.maps.LatLngLiteral | null>(null);
  const [selectedRestaurant, setSelectedRestaurant] =
    useState<Restaurant | null>(null);

  // console.log(`restaurant data: ${JSON.stringify(restaurantData)}`);
  // console.log(`current location`, currentLocation);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedRestaurant) {
      const { latitude, longitude } = selectedRestaurant;
      setRestaurantLocation({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
      console.log(
        `restaurant location: latitude: ${latitude}, longitude: ${longitude}`
      );
    }
  }, [selectedRestaurant]);

  const { isLoaded } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY as string,
    libraries,
  });

  console.log(`isLoaded:`, isLoaded);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded && window.google) {
      const fetchCurrentLocation = async () => {
        try {
          const position = await getCurrentPosition();
          const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
          setCurrentLocation(
            new window.google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
          );
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
      fetchCurrentLocation();
    }
  }, [isLoaded]);

  const getCurrentPosition = (): Promise<GeolocationPosition> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentLocation && window.google) {
      const updatedRestaurantData = restaurantData.map((restaurant) => {
        const restaurantLocation = new window.google.maps.LatLng(
          restaurant.latitude,
          restaurant.longitude
        );
        const distanceInKm = calculateDistanceBetweenLocations(
          currentLocation,
          restaurantLocation
        );
        // console.log(Number(distanceInKm.toFixed(2)));
        return { ...restaurant, distance: Number(distanceInKm.toFixed(2)) };
      });
      setRestaurantData(updatedRestaurantData);
    }
  }, [currentLocation]);

  return (
    <RestaurantMenuProvider>
      <LocationContext.Provider
        value={{
          restaurantLocation,
          currentLocation,
          distance,
          selectedRestaurant,
          setSelectedRestaurant,
          restaurantData,
          isLoaded,
          // loadEr/ror,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </LocationContext.Provider>
    </RestaurantMenuProvider>
  );
};
```

fetch restaurants:

**RestaurantMenuContext.tsx:**

```
"use client";

import { RestaurantMenuContextValue, Restaurant, Menu } from "types/types";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from "supabase/supabase";

const RestaurantMenuContext = createContext<
  RestaurantMenuContextValue | undefined
>(undefined);

export const useRestaurantMenuContext = (): RestaurantMenuContextValue => {
  const context = useContext(RestaurantMenuContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "useRestaurantMenuContext must be used within a RestaurantMenuProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

export const RestaurantMenuProvider: React.FC<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [restaurantData, setRestaurantData] = useState<Restaurant[]>([]);
  const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState<Menu[]>([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRestaurantData() {
      try {
        const { data: restaurantData, error: restaurantDataError } =
          await supabase
            .from("Restaurant")
            .select("id, name, photoUrl, location, latitude, longitude");
        console.log(`restaurantData: `, restaurantData);

        const { data: menuData, error: menuDataError } = await supabase
          .from("Menu")
          .select("*");

        if (restaurantDataError || menuDataError) {
          console.error(restaurantDataError);
          console.error(menuDataError);
        } else {
          setRestaurantData(restaurantData ?? []);
          setMenuData(menuData as Menu[]);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchRestaurantData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <RestaurantMenuContext.Provider
      value={{ restaurantData, setRestaurantData, menuData, isLoading }}
    >
      {children}
    </RestaurantMenuContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

display restaurants:

**app/lib/fetchDisplayRestaurants.tsx:**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState } from "react";
import slugify from "slugify";
import { useLocationContext } from "app/context/LocationContext";
import { Restaurant } from "types/types";
import Image from "next/image";
import { RestaurantMenuProvider } from "app/context/RestaurantMenuContext";

export default function DisplayRestaurants({
  isLoading,
}: {
  isLoading: boolean;
}) {
  const { restaurantData, setSelectedRestaurant } = useLocationContext();
  // const { isLoading } = useRestaurantMenuContext();
  // console.log(isLoading);
  console.log(`restaurantData: ${JSON.stringify(restaurantData)}`);
  console.log(`length: `, restaurantData?.length);
  // const { setSelectedRestaurant } = useLocationContext();
  const [restaurantPlaceholders, setRestaurantPlaceholders] = useState<
    JSX.Element[]
  >([]);

  // console.log(`distance:`, restaurantData);
  const handleRestaurantClick = (restaurant: Restaurant) => {
    console.log(`RESTAURANT: `, restaurant);
    setSelectedRestaurant(restaurant);
  };

  // const filteredRestaurants = restaurantData?.filter(
  //   (restaurant) => restaurant.distance && restaurant.distance <= 1
  // );

  // console.log(`filteredRestaurants: ${JSON.stringify(filteredRestaurants)}`);
  const displayRestaurants = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <RestaurantMenuProvider>
          {restaurantData?.map((restaurant) => (
            // <Fragment key={restaurant.name}>
            <div
              key={restaurant.name}
              className="relative h-32 mt-2 mb-4 bg-black"
              onClick={() => {
                console.log(`restaurant: ${JSON.stringify(restaurant)}`);
                handleRestaurantClick(restaurant);
              }}
            >
              <div className="relative h-full">
                {restaurant.photoUrl && (
                  <Image
                    src={restaurant.photoUrl}
                    alt={restaurant.name}
                    fill
                    className="object-cover opacity-50"
                  />
                )}
              </div>
              <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-white">
                <Link
                  href={`/restaurants/${slugify(
                    restaurant.name
                  ).toLowerCase()}`}
                >
                  <div>{restaurant.name}</div>
                </Link>
                <div>{restaurant.location}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </RestaurantMenuProvider>
      </>
    );
  };

  const showSkeleton = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {Array(5)
          .fill(null)
          .map((item, index) => {
            return (
              // <SkeletonTheme baseColor="#202020" highlightColor="#444">
              <div className="h-32 mt-2 mb-4 animate-pulse" key={index}>
                {/* // </SkeletonTheme> */}
                <div className="bg-stone-300 h-full"></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </>
    );
  };

  return <div>{isLoading ? showSkeleton() : displayRestaurants()}</div>;
}
```

**app/home/page.tsx:**

```
"use client";

import Footer from "components/footer";
import FetchDisplayRestaurants from "@lib/fetchDisplayRestaurants";
import { useDeliveryContext } from "./../context/DeliveryContext";
import { Toggle } from "./../../components/Toggle";
import { useRestaurantMenuContext } from "./../context/RestaurantMenuContext";
import { LocationProvider } from "app/context/LocationContext";
import { IoIosRestaurant } from "react-icons/io";
import { MdLocalGroceryStore } from "react-icons/md";

export default function HomePage() {
  const { toggleDelivery } = useDeliveryContext();
  const { isLoading } = useRestaurantMenuContext();
  console.log(isLoading);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex w-full mt-8 px-4">
        <Toggle onToggle={toggleDelivery} />
      </div>
      <div className="w-full flex mt-10 mb-4 px-3">
        <div className="h-20 w-1/2 justify-center flex bg-sky-200 mx-1 items-center">
          Restaurants <IoIosRestaurant />
        </div>
        <div className="h-20 w-1/2 justify-center flex bg-sky-200 mx-1 items-center">
          Grocery <MdLocalGroceryStore />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-full text-gray-50 flex flex-col lg:flex-row mb-20 px-4 rounded-lg">
        <LocationProvider>
          <FetchDisplayRestaurants isLoading={isLoading} />
        </LocationProvider>
      </div>
      <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 w-full bg-gray-50 py-3 shadow-xl">
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code